# What is the difference between "<T> T" and "T" return types in JavaDocs

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

Still wrapping my head around generics so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give one example of each in the JDK or in a third party library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both cases, the return type is `T`.

If you see `<T>` before though, it means that the generic type `T` has been defined at the method level:

```java
<T extends JustAnExample> T getThatThing() {
  // ...
}
```

If not, then it has probably been defined at the class level:

```java
class MyClass<T extends JustAnExample> {
  T getThatThing() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Or, it can technically also simply be a class named `T`, although those single-letter types usually refer to generics (purely by convention):

```java
class MyClass {
  T poorlyNamedTypeYuck() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Note that you don't have to use `T` as the return type:

```java
<T> void thisIsAlsoValid(T genericUsedHere, List<T> orElseWhere) {
  // ...
}
```